# Ruby: How to copy a word in a string containing a specific sequence of letters?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to read in a text file and iterate through every line. If the line contains "_u" then I want to copy that word in that line.

For example:

```
typedef struct {
    reg 1;
    reg 2;
} buffer_u;
```

I want to copy the word buffer_u.

This is what I have so far (everything up to how to copy the word in the string):

```
f_in = File.open( h_file )
test = h_file.read  
text.each_line do |line|
    if line.include? "_u"
        # copy word
        # add to output file
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "copy"? Copy to what?

Comment: You don't actually do anything with `f_in` and `test`,  and `text ` appears out of nowhere.

Comment: Sorry, test and text should have been the same name, my mistake. Will fix.

I want to assign the word to a string or just have a way so I can output the word to another file.

Comment: `word buffer_u` Do you have any idea of the legal characters that would constitute a `word` ?

Comment: Is `"_u"` a word or should it be ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make it harder than it has to be. If you want to scan a body of text for words that match a criteria, do just that:

```
text = "
word_u1
something
_u1 foo
bar _u2
another word_u2
typedef struct {
    reg 1;
    reg 2;
} buffer_u;
"

text.scan(/\w+/).select{ |w| w['_u'] }
# => ["word_u1", "_u1", "_u2", "word_u2", "buffer_u"]
```

Regex are useful but the more complex ("smarter") they are, they slower they run unless you are very careful to anchor them, as anchors give them hints on where to look. Without those, the engine tries a number of things to determine exactly what you want, and that can really bog down the processing.

I recommend instead simply grabbing the words in the text:

```
scan(/\w+/)
```

Then filtering out the ones that match:

```
select{ |w| w['_u'] }
```

Using select with a simple sub-string search `w['_u']` is extremely fast.

It could probably run faster using `split()` instead of `scan(/\w+/)` but you'll have to deal with cleaning up non-word characters.

Note: `\w` means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` so what we generally call a "word" character is actually a "variable" definition for most languages since words generally don't include digits or `_`.

You can probably reduce your code to:

```
File.read( h_file ).scan(/\w+/).select{ |w| w['_u'] }
```

That will return an array of matching words.

Caveat: Using `read` has scalability issues. If you're concerned about the size of the file being read (which you always should be) then use `foreach` and iterate over the file line-by-line. You will probably see no change in processing speed.

Comment: This works except 1 thing.  The array contains words in it like "_unused". If I can only get rid of that, that would be perfect!

Thank you so much for your help, you really taught me a lot!

Comment: There is nothing mentioning that in the question. It's a *little* important to give complete requirements before hand, not afterwards. Why doesn't that word match? It's easy to remove using a `reject` block or a minor adjustment to the `select` sub-string test.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
words = []
File.open( h_file ) { |file| file.each_line { |line|
  words << line.split.find { |a| a =~ /_u/ }
}}

words.compact!
# => [["buffer_u"]]

puts words
# buffer_u
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should catch a word ending with `_u`

```
(\w*_u)(?!\w)
```

The matching group will match a word ending with _u not followed by letters digits or underscores.

If you want _u to appear anywhere in a word use

```
(\w*_u\w*)
```

See [DEMO here](https://regex101.com/r/eQ4cN6/1).

Answer (score -1):

This will return all such words in the file, even if there are two or more in a line:

```
r = /
    \w*           # match >= 0 word characters
    _u            # match string
    \w*           # match >= 0 word characters 
    /x            # extended mode

File.read(fname).scan r
```

For example:

```
str = "Cat_u has 9 lives, \n!dog_u has none and \n pig_u_o and cow_u, 3."

fname = 'temp'
File.write(fname, str)
  #=> 63
```

Confirm the file contents:

```
File.read(fname)
  #=> "Cat_u has 9 lives, \n!dog_u has none and \n pig_u_o and cow_u, 3."
```

Extract strings:

```
File.read(fname).scan r
  #=> ["Cat_u", "dog_u", "pig_u_o", "cow_u"]
```

It's not difficult to modify this code to return at most one string per line. Simply read the file into an array of lines (or read a line at a time) and execute `s = line[r]; arr << s if s` for each line, where `r` is the above regex.